# In Android, can the backgrounded app be destroyed, but foreground service still active

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, dagger, foreground-service

I understand that activities may be freed up. But what about Dagger singleton objects created (associated with AppComponent which is tied to Application context)? Can they be freed up as well but foreground service still running (notification not dismissed by the user)?

When I search I come across statements like

```
When an app goes into the background, the Android system may decide to terminate the app's process to free up memory and other resources.
```

The behavior I see matches this possibility but don't know it for sure. App's process would include such objects as well?